# Qt offline installer and compatible c++ compiler installation

Tags: c++, qt

I ve been trying to download and install QT . I want to install the free version on multiple PC's and i want to use it for building very simple c++ desktop applications .

I tried to download and install the online free version installer but the internet speed stopped the installation process multiple times with the error

> Please check your connection

Unfortunately WIFI connection and speed are weak because the institute i am teaching at is located in a small village. Adding to the previous please note that hard drive space is critical for these PC's because they are  quite old (i3) 2GB of RAM and 256 HDD.

- what i tried to do ?

I ended up trying to install QT from the offline installer from this link :
[msvc2012_opengl-x86_64-offline.exe](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.2/5.2.0/)

It installed just fine , but then i get the following error :

> qt creator needs a compiler set up to build. configure a compiler in the kit options

I found a lot of solutions here for adding a compiler from Tools>Options.... and also tried to configure MIN_GW compiler following the instructions from the QT documentation Adding a Compiler section.

When i add the compilers the compiler prompts an exclamation mark and a prompt saying that the compiler is not compatible to this version of QT .

- What i want to do ?

Ideally i would want to find a compatible compiler for the  offline installer version OR maybe if someone could suggest any working links for an offline QT installer and a compatible c++ compiler for Windows 10.

Comment: I think the QT installer is depending on visual studio which i assume you didn't install and you do no have the intention to this given the specs. What windows version is installed on the pc's?

Comment: it's windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the MinGW version of Qt, it includes the required MinGW compiler. It is available from the same link you provided. (However I would recommend you to use 5.9 or 5.6 which are both LTS versions.)

Otherwise you have to make sure that you have the matching MS Visual Studio version installed. For `msvc2012_opengl-x86_64-offline.exe` you need Visual Studio 2012. The *express* editions usually work, but not for 64 bit, which is what you downloaded. (The *community* editions of later Visual Studios do include a 64 bit compiler.)

Comment: from what i understand you are saying that i would better go with this  :  https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.6/5.6.1/qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw492-5.6.1.exe  and it will not require a visual studio version and it also has the compiler embedded in the installer ?

Comment: More like https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.6/5.6.3/qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw492-5.6.3.exe, but yes.